# Query on using System.getProperty("line.separator") on Linux

Tags: java, linux, properties, system

I am using the below code on Linux OS and it is not working as expected. I want to replace all line separator coming in lsString with space

```
lsString = lsString .replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), " "));
```

But when I use the below piece of code it works.

```
lsString = lsString .replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", " "));
```

I do not want to hard code line separator but instead, get it from properties. I tried doing as below but no luck as such.

```
  String lsLnSeparator =  System.getProperty("line.separator").replaceAll("\\", "\\\\");
  lsString = lsString .replaceAll(lsLnSeparator, " ");
```

Please suggest as I want this same piece of code to work on Windows, MAC, Unix as well.

Comment: Have you tried `System.lineSeparator()`?

Comment: Welcome! Pattern.quote method is your friend.

Comment: Yes, initial tried lsString = lsString .replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), " ")); on Linux but didn't work. Does it depends on Java version ?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, will try out as below:


String lsLnSeparator = Pattern.quote(System.lineSeparator());
lsString = lsString.replaceAll(lsLnSeparator, " "));

Comment: Still no success even after using Pattern.quote. Please suggest as it works on Windows OS but not on Linux OS.

Code Snippet:
String lsLnSeparator = Pattern.quote(System.lineSeparator()); 

lsString = lsString.replaceAll(lsLnSeparator, " "));

Comment: Thank you all, the problem is that the java web application when deployed in a linux box does not understand ENTERs pressed from a Windows client box. So, if Server is Windows and Client is also Windows, it works fine. If server is Linux and Client is Windows, it does not work. 

So either of the below expression will work on all OS.

lsString = lsString.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]", " ");
 
lsString = lsString.replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", " ");